# How can I add animation/fade to modal/dialogue boxes?

Tags: 8, theming, modal-dialogs

The current state of a modal/dialog opening in Drupal 8 (and 7 for that matter) is pretty clunky from a user experience perspect. Leveraging some type of animation/fade would really enhance the elegance + cohesiveness of the modal. I notice bootstrap allows a "fade" class on the modal, which gives it a fade effect (I assume). Is there a way to add this type (or any type) of animation to a Drupal 8 modal without needing bootstrap? Am I missing something simple?

Edit:
Thanks for quick replies and patience with a newbie. So I'm opening a node/add form into a modal with a link like so..

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:800}" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/node/add/article">Add Article</a>
```

I'd like the modal to open/close with a fade effect (or slide in, etc).
Is there a way to leverage JS, CSS or Drupal itself to create this animation?

Is there a better solution all together to displaying a node/add form in a popup/lightbox type element with ajax?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I fear, even you experienced the clunky behavior when using Drupal, your question is too broad for this group and therefore not well-suited to be answered here. Please note, that this group is about answering Drupal related, to-the-point questions when you experience problems while working on your own solutions. (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Missing JavaScript effects, UI improvements or general coding help is off-topic here.

Comment: perhaps writing what you did and what is missing from the solution will lead to some answers ... did you try the bootstrap theme ?

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. Hopefully the edit above brings more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need the modal to do? I often use animated modals for my Drupal projects - http://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/

It seems to work pretty well for menus and forms in my experience.

It uses animate.css ( https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ ) which you can use also to create some nice transitional effects.

Comment: Looking for the modal to open a node/add form. See my edit above. Not sure how I'd tie that into the animatedModal.js (with the need for ajax, and the removal of the header, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-options='{"width":"800","dialogClass":"custom-class-modal","show":"fadeIn","hide":"fadeOut"}' data-dialog-type="modal" href="/node/add/article">Add Article</a>
```